# Converting Tab to Shp Using OGR2OGR with Python on linux

Tags: python, ogr2ogr, linux

First I downloaded  http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples/ogr2ogr.py and I am importing this. How can I get ogr2ogr to run in my script?

Nothing seems to be working and I'm not sure how to continue problem solving.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
import ogr2ogr
import sys

if __name__=="__main__":
ogr2ogr.main('-f', "Mapinfo File", '/home/firstuser/birmingham/Wood.tab', "/home/firstuser/birmingham/Wood.shp")
```

With this I get 
    main() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

and when I do:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
ogr2ogr.main('-f', "Mapinfo File", '/home/firstuser/birmingham/Wood.tab')
```

I get:

```
Usage: ogr2ogr [--help-general] [-skipfailures] [-append] [-update] [-gt n]
           [-select field_list] [-where restricted_where]
           [-progress] [-sql <sql statement>]
           [-spat xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-preserve_fid] [-fid FID]
           [-a_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-s_srs srs_def]
           [-f format_name] [-overwrite] [[-dsco NAME=VALUE] ...]
           [-simplify tolerance]
           [-fieldTypeToString All|(type1[,type2]*)] [-explodecollections]
           dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name
           [-lco NAME=VALUE] [-nln name] [-nlt type] [-dim 2|3] [layer [layer ...]]

 -f format_name: output file format name, possible values are:
 -f "ESRI Shapefile"
 -f "MapInfo File"
 -f "TIGER"
 -f "S57"
 -f "DGN"
 -f "Memory"
 -f "BNA"
 -f "CSV"
 -f "GML"
 -f "GPX"
 -f "KML"
 -f "GeoJSON"
 -f "Interlis 1"
 -f "Interlis 2"
 -f "GMT"
 -f "SQLite"
 -f "ODBC"
 -f "MSSQLSpatial"
 -f "PostgreSQL"
 -f "MySQL"
 -f "PCIDSK"
 -f "DXF"
 -f "Geoconcept"
 -f "GeoRSS"
 -f "GPSTrackMaker"
 -f "PGDump"
 -f "GPSBabel"
 -append: Append to existing layer instead of creating new if it exists
  -overwrite: delete the output layer and recreate it empty
  -update: Open existing output datasource in update mode
  -progress: Display progress on terminal. Only works if input layers have the "fast      feature count" capability
  -select field_list: Comma-delimited list of fields from input layer to
                 copy to the new layer (defaults to all)
  -where restricted_where: Attribute query (like SQL WHERE)
  -sql statement: Execute given SQL statement and save result.
  -skipfailures: skip features or layers that fail to convert
  -gt n: group n features per transaction (default 200)
  -spat xmin ymin xmax ymax: spatial query extents
  -simplify tolerance: distance tolerance for simplification.
  -dsco NAME=VALUE: Dataset creation option (format specific)
  -lco  NAME=VALUE: Layer creation option (format specific)
  -nln name: Assign an alternate name to the new layer
  -nlt type: Force a geometry type for new layer.  One of NONE, GEOMETRY,
  POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, MULTIPOINT,
  MULTIPOLYGON, or MULTILINESTRING.  Add "25D" for 3D layers.
  Default is type of source layer.
  -dim dimension: Force the coordinate dimension to the specified value.
  -fieldTypeToString type1,...: Converts fields of specified types to
  fields of type string in the new layer. Valid types are :
  Integer, Real, String, Date, Time, DateTime, Binary, IntegerList, RealList,
  StringList. Special value All can be used to convert all fields to strings.
  -a_srs srs_def: Assign an output SRS
  -t_srs srs_def: Reproject/transform to this SRS on output
  -s_srs srs_def: Override source SRS

  Srs_def can be a full WKT definition (hard to escape properly),
  or a well known definition (ie. EPSG:4326) or a file with a WKT
  definition.
```

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450285/executing-command-line-programs-from-within-python

Comment: also for a few examples,
http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet

Comment: @Antony This would work if i was in windows and say running FWtoos, but i am in linux and need to call upon the ogr2ogr.py module/script. correct?

Comment: @Antony Got it working, installed FWtools on linux and used os.system to use the command. Thanks!!

Comment: Could you post the solution as an answer below so that the next person looking for the solution can easily find it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the solution to OP's question is to wrap the arguments as a list, and offset the list by one empty string (It's expecting the first argument to be the script name, so you can just ignore that argument:

```
ogr2ogr.main(['', '-f', "Mapinfo File", '/home/firstuser/birmingham/Wood.tab'])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use bash shell in linux, you can use $locate ogr2ogr.py to locate the ogr2ogr's path, and then you can use the following code

```
$python PATH/ogr2ogr.py -f PARAMETERS PATH/YourToFileName PATH/YourFromFileName
```